# Как убрать обновление после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: jquery, ajax

Такая проблема, есть форма для подписки, здесь она работает правильно, но у меня после нажатия на кнопку обновляется страница и резко кидает вверх, и из-за этого не видно эффекта что границы подчеркнулись. Как убрать обновление? знаю, как-то через ajax можно, не пойму как сделать это.

```js
 function send() {
        var valid = true;
        var elems = document.forms[0].elements;
        for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length; i++) {
            if (elems[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text' ||
                elems[i].getAttribute('type') == 'email' ||
                elems[i].getAttribute('type') == 'password') {

                if (elems[i].value == '') {

                    elems[i].style.border = '2px solid #ff3366';
                    valid = false;
                }

            }
        }


    }


    window.onload = function () {

        document.forms[0].onmouseover = function () {
            var elems = document.forms[0].elements;
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
                if (elems[i].value != '')

                    elems[i].style.border = ' 2px solid transparent';
            elems[i].style.transition = ' 1s';
        }
    }
```

```html
   <form id="application" action="#" method="POST" name="application  " onclick="return send();" >


                    <input name="name" type="text"  id="applicationName" maxlength="20" placeholder="Your Name"    />

                    <input name="email" type="email" id="applicationEmail" maxlength="20" placeholder="Email Adress" />
                    <input name="telephone" type="password" id="applicationTelephone" maxlength="20" placeholder="Create a Password"  />
                    <button class="applicationButton" type="submit"   form="application"><strong> GET STRTED - FREE FOREVER!</strong> </button>

                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю Вам так нужно:

```
function send() {
    var valid = true;
    var elems = document.forms[0].elements;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text' ||
            elems[i].getAttribute('type') == 'email' ||
            elems[i].getAttribute('type') == 'password') {

            if (elems[i].value == '') {

                elems[i].style.border = '2px solid #ff3366';
                valid = false;
            }

        }
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: создал отдельную страницу  там работает, на той, в которой нужно сделать не работает(не пдчеркивает поля)

Comment: Вероятно дело в адресации. Явно указано что первая форма на странице (document.forms[0]), а на той странице, где Вам это нужно - эта форма может быть и не первой.

Answer (score -1):

добавь событие при нажатии кнопки

`<button class="applicationButton" type="submit"   form="application"     onclick="return false;">`

и аякс писать сюда
либо сделать перезагрузку не заметной пользователю:

`<iframe name="myIFR" style="display: none"></iframe>
 <form id="application" target="myIFR" method="POST" name="application"  onclick="return send();" >`

Comment: тогда не работает скрипт

Comment: можешь попробовать
`<button class="applicationButton" type="submit"   form="application" onclick="send(); return false;">` и с формы вызов send() убрать.. у меня вызов функции отправки в консоли отображает

Comment: обновления нет, но скрипт  не работает, тогда как запустить проверку сриптом?